# How to replace latest Jetty 9 in spring-boot?

Tags: jetty, spring-boot

In spring-boot, when I added the following dependency, Jetty 8 is being used.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, if I would like to use Jetty 9 in spring-boot. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it once a while ago and decided to stick with jetty 8 because we didn't want to depend on java 7 explicitly. It worked at the time though with very little effort. Depending on whether the jetty jar packages changed between 8 and 9, you might be able to just set

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>...</jetty.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

If that doesn't work then you will need to explicitly include the jetty dependencies in your project in whatever form you need them. From there it's a standard project configuration problem (nothing to do with Spring or Spring Boot).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Since the very reason to use spring-boot is to have all the things works without much configuration...so I would continue to try spring-boot with default Jetty version. Thanks again!